# Deploying a Flask Application Without Internet Access

Tags: python, flask, module, flask-sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I created a Flask project that works on my laptop. I want to run it on another laptop without internet access. How can I run the program with all modules working properly without installing anything? I shared the complete folder with modules, but it still doesn't work. Please help

i tried to run it on another laptop without installing anthing anyother things just want to run it without internet access even i shared complete folder of the project

Comment: Collect the wheels for each module and install them offline.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `pip download ...` can download modules without installing them - so you can get modules on one computer and later use `pip install ...`  on other computer to install them from local files. You can download modules directly from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org) .

Comment: btw: you have to know what CPU and OS you have on other computer because some modules have different files for different CPUs and different systems.

Comment: other method can be to use [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) to create `.exe` file (or rather self-extracting `.zip` file). It tries to add all needed module to this file. But sometimes it may have problem to detect what modules it may need and you have to use special file `spec` to manually add needed modules. You have to also know that if you use `pyinstaller` on `Windows` then it creates `.exe` which works only `Windows`, and if you use `pyinstaller` on `Linux` then `.exe` works only on `Linux`. Similar: `cx_freeze`, `py2exe`, probably `py2app` (for Mac)